# Canvas presents problems when resizing the screen

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have this design and works perfectly: http://jsfiddle.net/98Bgq/22/

```
var offsetX = canvasOffset.left;
var offsetY = canvasOffset.top;
var scrollX = $canvas.scrollLeft();
var scrollY = $canvas.scrollTop();
```

But when I resize the screen of my browser, it seems the canvas begins to operate in a totally different way than normal, in the above example can not I click a few more parts of the design, how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using jQuery, it will probably be easiest to use `event.pageX`. E.g.

```
mouseX = e.pageX - $canvas.offset().left;
mouseY = e.pageY - $canvas.offset().top;
```

Edit: For non-jQuery, this works well:

```
mouseX = e.hasOwnProperty('offsetX') ? e.offsetX : e.layerX;
mouseY = e.hasOwnProperty('offsetY') ? e.offsetY : e.layerY;
```

`event.pageY/X` returns the mouse position relative to the top/left edge of the document. `$elmnt.offset()` returns the coordinates of the element relative to the document. So subtracting the latter from the former gives you the relative position of the mouse in the canvas.

`event.offsetY/X`/`event.layerY/X` give you the coordinate of the event relative to the current layer. `layerX` doesn't work with chrome, so if it's not present, `offsetX` is used instead.

Answer (score 0):

offset and scroll might change on a window resize : handle the resize event and recompute them :

this fiddle seems to work : 
http://jsfiddle.net/gamealchemist/98Bgq/24/

code :

```
var offsetX = 0, offsetY = 0;
var scrollX = 0, scrollY = 0;

function computeOffset() {
 canvasOffset = $canvas.offset();
 offsetX = canvasOffset.left;
 offsetY = canvasOffset.top;
 scrollX = $canvas.scrollLeft();
 scrollY = $canvas.scrollTop();
}

computeOffset();

window.onresize = computeOffset;
```